# Android DatePicker showing wrong year above calendar

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a date picker fragment and am running into a problem where the year above the calendar isn't updating properly.

The first problem I have is that if I use the up/down year buttons the title of the fragment changes to "Set date" and the year above the calendar doesn't update (the day grid does).

The second problem is when I open it with dates well into the future or the past the dates it shows in the title and above the calendar are very wrong.

Going into the future the breakpoint occurs between 2037/4/11 and 2038/4/11.  While I haven't hunted down the exact day I suspect a 32bit unix time lurking in the background is somehow involved.

Going into the past however the break occurs between 1902/4/11 and 1901/4/11; which doesn't align with the start of a 32bit timestamp but does correspond to the invalid dates seen when crossing into 2038.

This happens on both the 4.1 tablets I have for testing and in 4.1 and 4.2 AVDs.  Screenshots are cropped from tablet AVDs.

At this point I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or have found a bug in the OS itself.

Initial state, loaded with today:
[image: Initial state, loaded with today]

After pressing the + year button, wrong title year above calendar not updated:
[image: After pressing the + year button]

Loaded with a 2037 date, initial state is good:
[image: Loaded with a 2037 date]

Loaded with a 2038 date, note time warps back to 1902 in the title and above the calendar:
[image: Loaded with a 2038 date]

Loaded with a 1902 date, nothing wrong:
[image: Loaded with a 1902 date]

Loaded with a 1901 date, note time warps forward to 2037 in the title and above the calendar:
[image: Loaded with a 1901 date]

My fragment class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static int _month = 0;
    private static int _day = 0;
    private static int _year = 0;
    private static int _buttonId = 0;

    public DatePickerFragment(){
    }

    public static final DatePickerFragment newInstance(int buttonId, int year, int month, int day) {
        DatePickerFragment f = new DatePickerFragment();
        _buttonId = buttonId;
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _day = day;
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),  mDateSetListener, _year, _month, _day);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    //update the control whose press opened the DatePpickerFragment
            Button _button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById (_buttonId);
            if(_button != null) {
                _button.setText(month+1 + "/" + day + "/" + year);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And the code to install the button handler that opens the fragment:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(buttonID);

    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button button = (Button) v;
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                c.setTime(df.parse(button.getText().toString()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Do nothing. Calendar defaults to the current date. Use that instead.
            }

            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(button.getId(), year, month, day);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I used your code but I didn't face any problem as you mentioned ! although I was getting same problem when I used plain dialog instead of FragmentDialog. I think this is a bug in date picker.